# input from file in batch file problem

Tags: postgresql, input, batch-file

i need to enter password two time for this command when it ask

```
createuser -h localhost -P -p 5432 -s -d -r -e postgres
```

i tried

```
createuser -h localhost -P -p 5432 -s -d -r -e postgres < temp.txt
```

where `temp.txt` contains

> password
>   password

it still asks for password

any suggestions?

Comment: Could the part that asks for a password be a separate process that is started by `createuser`?

Answer (score 3):

The [`createuser`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html) program probably makes its own connection to the terminal rather than reading from its standard input, this is common behavior where passwords are concerned. You'll probably have better luck using the SQL [`CREATE ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) rather than `createuser`:

```
echo "CREATE ROLE postgres CREATEROLE CREATEDB SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';" \   
    | psql -h localhost -p 5432 databasename
```

Where "databasename" is the name of your database.

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html):

> createuser is a wrapper around the SQL command CREATE ROLE. There is no effective difference between creating users via this utility and via other methods for accessing the server.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the database name on `psql`, please see my update.

Comment: but first i want need to create user and on that user i will create database so at this stage database would not available